# Pass input selection to another input field

Tags: next.js

How can I pass the selected option from the React Select component to the input of that has an onChange function. Am I able to create a dedicated OnChange function for the Island input, If I do that I will have an issue with the current onChange function as they will clash, correct?

```
function onChange(e) {
        setRental(() => ({ ...rental, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
      }

          <div>
            <Select placeholder={" Select Island"} options={options} />
          </div>

          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="Island"
              placeholder="Island"
              value={rental.Island}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
```

This is the full code

```
import { API, Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { createRental } from "../graphql/mutations";
import Select from "react-select";
import Async, { useAsync } from "react-select/async";

const initialState = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  MaxNumberOfGuest: "",
  MaxNumberOfAdults: "",
  MaxNumberOfChildren: "",
  NumberOfBedrooms: "",
  NumberOfBaths: "",
  PricePerNight: "",
  AdditionalCosts: "",
  StreetName: "",
  Area: "",
  ZipCode: "",
  Island: "",
  lat: "",
  lon: "",
};

function CreateRental() {
  const options = [
    { value: "Tenerife", label: "Tenerife" },
    { value: "Lanzarote", label: "Lanzarote" },
    { value: "Fuerteventura", label: "Fuerteventura" },
    { value: "Gran Canaria", label: "Gran Canaria" },
  ];

  const [rental, setRental] = useState(initialState);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);
  const {
    title,
    description,
    MaxNumberOfGuest,
    MaxNumberOfAdults,
    MaxNumberOfChildren,
    NumberOfBedrooms,
    NumberOfBaths,
    PricePerNight,
    AdditionalCosts,
    StreetName,
    Area,
    ZipCode,
    Island,
    lat,
    lon,
  } = rental;
  const router = useRouter();

  function onChange(e) {
    setRental(() => ({ ...rental, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  }
  function onChangeHandlerTwo(e) {
    setRental(() => ({ Island, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  }
  async function createNewRental() {
    if (
      !title ||
      !description ||
      !MaxNumberOfGuest ||
      !MaxNumberOfAdults ||
      !MaxNumberOfChildren ||
      !NumberOfBedrooms ||
      !NumberOfBaths ||
      !PricePerNight ||
      !AdditionalCosts ||
      !StreetName ||
      !Area ||
      !ZipCode ||
      !Island ||
      !lat ||
      !lon
    )
      return;
    const id = uuid();
    rental.id = id;
    // If there is an image uploaded, store it in S3 and add it to the post metadata
    if (image) {
      const fileName = `${image.name}_${uuid()}`;
      rental.FeaturedImage = fileName;
      await Storage.put(fileName, image);
    }

    await API.graphql({
      query: createRental,
      variables: { input: rental },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    router.push(`/rentals/${id}`);
  }

  async function uploadImage() {
    hiddenFileInput.current.click();
  }
  function handleChange(e) {
    const fileUploaded = e.target.files[0];
    if (!fileUploaded) return;
    setImage(fileUploaded);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold tracking-wide mt-6">
          Create new rental
        </h1>
        <input
          onChange={onChange}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
          value={rental.title}
          className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none w-full font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
        />
        <textarea
          onChange={onChange}
          name="description"
          placeholder="description"
          value={rental.description}
          className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none w-full font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
        />
        <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="MaxNumberOfGuest"
              placeholder="Maximum number of guests"
              value={rental.MaxNumberOfGuest}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="MaxNumberOfAdults"
              placeholder="Maximum number of adults"
              value={rental.MaxNumberOfAdults}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="MaxNumberOfChildren"
              placeholder="Maximum number of children"
              value={rental.MaxNumberOfChildren}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="NumberOfBedrooms"
              placeholder="Number of bedrooms"
              value={rental.NumberOfBedrooms}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="NumberOfBaths"
              placeholder="Number of baths"
              value={rental.NumberOfBaths}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="PricePerNight"
              placeholder="Price Per Night (£)"
              value={rental.PricePerNight}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="AdditionalCosts"
              placeholder="Additional Costs (£) "
              value={rental.AdditionalCosts}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-semibold tracking-wide mt-6">Address</h2>
        <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="StreetName"
              placeholder="Street Name"
              value={rental.StreetName}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="Area"
              placeholder="Area"
              value={rental.Area}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="ZipCode"
              placeholder="Zip Code"
              value={rental.ZipCode}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <Select
              placeholder={" Select Island"}
              options={options}
              changeHandler={onChangeHandlerTwo}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="Island"
              placeholder="Island"
              value={rental.Island}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="lat"
              placeholder="Latitude"
              value={rental.lat}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              onChange={onChange}
              name="lon"
              placeholder="Longitude"
              value={rental.lon}
              className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-6">
          {image && <img src={URL.createObjectURL(image)} className="my-4" />}
          <input
            type="file"
            ref={hiddenFileInput}
            className="hidden"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <button
            className="bg-purple-600 text-white font-semibold px-8 py-2 rounded-lg mr-2"
            onClick={uploadImage}
          >
            Upload Featured Image
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="mb-4 bg-blue-600 text-white font-semibold px-8 py-2 rounded-lg"
            onClick={createNewRental}
          >
            Create Rental
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default CreateRental;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove react select and use a default select type. This allows the onChange to work by the name field.

```
<select
          name="Island"
          value={rental.island}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder={"Select Island"}
          className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 "
        >
          <option value="" disabled selected hidden>
            Select Island
          </option>
          <option value="Tenerife">Tenerife</option>
          <option value="Lanzarote">Lanzarote</option>
          <option value="Fuerteventura">Fuerteventura</option>
          <option value="Gran Canaria">Gran Canaria</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, if you are wondering that you can create two onChange functions within the single component, it's not work as you expected, because you are creating two functions with different body but same name. You can give any name to handlers of the component. Only thing matter is where you are linking those handlers in your JSX.

```
      function onChangeHandlerOne(e) {
        setRental(() => ({ ...rental, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
      }


      function onChangeHandlerTwo(e) {
            setRental(() => ({ ...rental, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
      }

      <div>
        <Select placeholder={" Select Island"} options={options} changeHandler={onChangeHandlerTwo}/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          onChange={onChangeHandlerOne}
          name="Island"
          placeholder="Island"
          value={rental.Island}
          className="border-b pb-2 text-lg my-4 focus:outline-none font-light text-gray-500 placeholder-gray-500 y-2"
        />
      </div>
```

1. In Select component, you can call the handler that you have recieved
   via props when user selects any option.
2. Below is the psuedo code. You can link the handler that you have recieved from the parent component over here.

   ```
   # If you want to pass the event object to your handler make
   'onChange={(event)=>props.changeHandler(event)}'

   const Select = (props) => {
       return(
           <Form.Control
               as="select"
               # additional attributes
               onChange={props.changeHandler}
           >
           <option value="burger">Burger</option>
           <option value="pizza">Pizza</option>
       </Form.Control>

   )}
   ```

Let me know, if I understood incorrectly or if I missed anything.

Comment: Sorry I don't really follow, I want the Select component to update the value of the Input, Then on submit, it needs to update the api. I will update the code to show the full page.